# Coordinates on 3d Circle

Tags: calculus, trigonometry, circles, coordinate-systems

**Problem:**

Given is is the centerpoint $C$ of a circle and two extra reference points $R$ and $E$, which are laying on the circle.
While as the line $\overline{CE}$ is defining the zero point on the circle of a given degree $α$ (clockwise rotation). Point $F$ is also on the very same circle. Therefore all of the points are on one in space rotated plane, on the circle.
Line $\overline{CF}$ is $α$ degrees away from line $\overline{CE}$. How can I get the XYZ coordinates of Point $F$?
($R ≠ E$)
[Fig. 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/56T1E.jpg)

Fig. 1: Illustration of described problem

- Note that $\overline{CR}$ is NOT necessarily parallel to $\overline{CF}$
- $\overline{CR}$ to $\overline{CE}$ not necessarily orthogonal
- all Points lay in one 3d circular plane
- in Fig. 1 a second circle is drawn orthogonal to the XY Plane just for better relation understanding (not a projection)
- The points $E$, $C$ and $R$ are defining the circles rotation in space, while $F$ is the point to move around on this circle (with a specific degree $\alpha$)

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Thanks!

Comment: I think you must also have angle between RC and CF.

Comment: @sirous Thank you for your suggestion. But I think you can calculate with the cosine Law!? Not necessarily correct.

Comment: @sirous But do you know how to do it then? I am really out of ideas right now :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

Hint:

In 3D there can be infinite points like F such that $\angle ECF=\alpha$ and also  $\angle RCF=\beta$. They are on two conic surface vertex on C with axis  CE and CR respectively. The intersection of these two surfaces makes two lines. Any point like F on these lines is such  that $\angle ECF=\alpha$ and $\angle RCF=\beta$.So you have to find equations of these conic surfaces.For this take for example xy plane. Draw a line angle with EC as $\alpha$ . Now revolve it about CE and find the equation of produced surface. Now draw a line which make angle $\beta$ with RC and revolve it about RC anf find it' equation. The system of thses two equations give the equations of lines resulting by intersection.Now to find coordinates of F you solve this system of equations:

$\begin{cases} y=mx \\x^2+y^2=r^2 \end {cases}$

Where $m=tan (\alpha)$ and r is  length of CF. So in adition to the angle you have you must also have r.Find x or y from first equation, put it in second equation and find x and y of point F.

Comment: Thank you very much for your input. I am really trying to understand what the illustration should display. Why are there cones around $CR$ and $CE$? And not ONE circle that is connecting $R$, $E$, $C$ and $F$? As all Point should lay in one plane right?

Comment: If E, R and c are on one plane then F can not be on that plane. Otherwise there will a 2D orientation.

Comment: I think it can. There might be a misunderstanding of what the problem is (most likely my mistake though). The Circle is defined by three points in space with c the middle point. Therefore those 3 points must laying in a **rotated** plane in space(defined by the circle). Now additionally one point **on** this -in space rotated- circle is taken. All points are laying on one rotated plane. This point isn't just randomly put on the circle. It can be found by an angle from a reference line created by the centerpoint and a reference point (both on the circle, as they were used to create the circle).

Comment: Sorry about misleading instructions. I would be really happy if you could tell what to do better in the future. But is it now more clearly or still not understandable? Should I upload a overworked graphical visualisation?

Comment: @Paul, I edited my answer and showed how to find coordinates of  F.Good luck.

Comment: Thanks, that for sure will help some people! For my purpose I actually used a different approach, that seemed easier to implement (see answer).

Answer (score 0):

I am going to answer how such a problem can be solved in a different way:

All lines to the points must be converted to vectors. A vector axis perpendicular to the circles face must be created. Then the vector of $CE$ is taken as the vector to rotate around the created axis vector, by theta degrees(counter clockwise rotation). This rotation and the vector of the new position can be calculated with the [**Rodrigues' rotation formula**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rodrigues%27_rotation_formula)!
See also: [**Quaternion rotation**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternion)